# How to reform dent on hair due to long usage of head-phones?

Tags: headphones, hair

I often wear headphones for extended periods of time, and they tend to leave a "dent" in my hair, a sort of depression in the shape of a band on top of my head. How would I:

a) Prevent this from happening

and/or

b) Remove of this dent quickly

I have tried to position my headphones in different places, but to no avail; they are either too uncomfortable to wear in those positions or they fall off. Showering sometimes removes these dents, but they do not always, and I may end up in a situation where I can't shower.

Comment: Opposed to wearing a hat of some kind?

Comment: @J.Musser Yes I am, but clever nonetheless XD

Comment: Opposed to looking dumb while wearing the headphones?

Comment: I've seen people wear headphones with the band that's supposed to go over the head, under the chin....I don't know if that helps you, though.

Comment: Yeah chinstrap method all the way.

Comment: You are lucky its just your hair, I got a dent in my Head itself where my headset rests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**My solutions:**

- Wear a hat or loosen the band to the headphones.
- Wear the headphones with the rest around your neck, i.e. wear them the wrong way.
- Thread your hair on top of the head rest portion. Don't have your hair under the headrest/earmuff portion.
- Wetting your hair with a spray bottle of water that you carry with you or going to a sink to wet it can remove the dent.

Solutions that may be helpful from [loevelyish.com](http://www.lovelyish.com/2012/01/02/ask-a-stylist-whats-a-headphone-friendly-hair-style/):

- Put your hair in curls. IDK about this, it may not be your thing.
- Wear a headband or other similar device.

  > I always say, if you're scared of damaging your style, just pre-damage
  >   it on your own terms so you're immune to the evil ways of the headset.
  >   Clear your hair away from your ears before you put the phones on so
  >   there isn't any hair getting creased in between, and brace the top of
  >   the headset on top of your cutie pie headband and voila! OR you can
  >   just use the headband when you're headed out for happy hour. Put it in
  >   the spot where the headset was and it looks like your hair meant for
  >   it to be there. Just make sure (for comfort's sake, too) to go for a
  >   nice wide one similar to the width of your headset.
- Bring some styling products with you. This might be hairspray, etc.

  > Maybe just one, even. The grocery store loves to accommodate with
  >   little tiny versions of all your favorites (as do salons), and for you
  >   it might just be a matter of a little hairspray or a little paste to
  >   fluff your style back up and kill the crease. You might use the
  >   products to just rearrange your hairstyle before drinks or just smooth
  >   it back into a ponytail, but it's all about being prepared.

[Headset Hair: Correction/Prevention?](http://www.vvv-gaming.com/forum/topic/55157-headset-hair-correctionprevention/) This site was chock full of lame advice, but you might try:

- Shaving your head. This is lame, but will definitely work because you will have no hair.
- Wearing a Hoodie. Or as RayOfLight says:

  > i wear my hoodie on my head first, then i have the headphone over my head

**Maybe Different ways to wear Headphones:**

[Head-fi.org](http://www.head-fi.org/t/394321/which-headset-doesnt-ruin-hair-not-a-joke):

> Another way you could cope with this is by buying crappy headphones
>   that go around the back of your head rather than on top. But these
>   tend to hurt after a while, and SQ probably won't be comparable to
>   anything we discuss here. You could also just try using earbuds or
>   IEM's that deliver good SQ.
>
> The most forgiving full sized headphone I can imagine will probably be
>   the Audio Technica line-up of headphones. They're all pretty light
>   weight, and they've got that wing design that allows the headphones to
>   just rest on your head rather than gripping it tightly all around.
>   However, if the wings do squish down on your hair, then you're just
>   going to end up with an even funnier look than a normal set since
>   you'll have the sides flattened down, and a portion in the middle
>   still sticking up.
>
> Also, washing your hair more than once a day (many say more than once
>   every other day) with shampoo/conditioner is known for making hair
>   oily and problematic in general.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me ALL of the time.

The easiest and most effective way to remove the hair dents is to loosen it by applying warm water to your hair, it works like an iron with clothes, the heat loosens up the hair and allows it to fall back into normal shape.

I do this pretty much every night, works every time...I also have large ear style headphones that cover your ear, this causes hair around my ears to flatten and look odd along with the band going across my head.

This trick will also help you in the morning if you get bed head, try it and see for yourself.

This trick will fix all of those issues, quick and easy without modifying the way you wear headphones etc...

Answer (score 1):

Wear your headphones at the front of your hair, where the headphones normally don't get near the back of your hair. Put it closer to your forehead.

Also, try to LOOSEN your headphones. If none of these are working, just wear a hat or use earbuds.

Answer (score 1):

Use straightening irons and frizzese then comb hair forwards or backwards or which ever way you wear your parting and use a strong gell with pomade afterwards to keep it all nice straight and flat,